# How to read a gzip file and send out to browser and let the browser decode it in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, gzip

Because of some non-programming restriction, I temporary cannot use the most updated node.js Express and Connect.  I have to stick with 2 subversion behind.

So, now, I have to do my only gzip javascript (because of older version doesn't take care of ETag, etc).

Here is what I do: (I had the gzipped file which is a working one)

```
fs.readFile('my.js.gz', function(err, data) {
  if (!err) {
   gzipJsFile = data;
  }
}


app.get('my.js', function(req, res) {
   // assume req.headers.accept-encoding contains gzip
   res.header('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
   res.header('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
   res.header('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
   res.header('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
   res.header('Vary', 'Accept-Encoding');
   res.send(gzipJsFile);
});
```

And the browser cannot unzip it.

I use Friddler. it complains there is Content-Length mismatch.    And It also complains the magic number in Gzip header is not correct.

I'm wondering, if I'm doing the correct way to read the gzip file and send it to the HTTP response?

Comment: "I have to stick with 2 subversion behind." Tell management that this is ridiculious. Versions two sub versions behind aren't more "stable" they are just full of bugs. Just overwrite management on this and install the latests versions. Lie to them if neccessary

Comment: I know.   However, the product going on soft launch in 3 days.  Then after that, I can upgrade and test with newest version. I have to update Mongo, Node... etc.  every package. It will take few days to have a thorough test if it goes smooth.  else, more than a week.  so, i'm looking for a temp solution now. :)